# Using select.poll() on a nonblocking file descriptor

Tags: python, linux, select, named-pipes

I have a named pipe opened in non-blocking mode:

```
fd = os.open('mypipe', os.O_RDONLY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

I want to be able to know if there's something to read **with a timeout**, so I tried to use select:

```
poller = select.poll()
poller.register(fd, select.POLLIN)
```

But when I try to poll and specify a timeout:

```
poller.poll(3000)
```

...it always returns immediately, even if there's nothing to read.

**My question is this**: is it possible to use timeouts with poll() on a file descriptor opened with O_NONBLOCK flag? Is it possible that I'm doing it wrong, and there is another way to achieve this?